# Where do the arguments passed to slots come from?

Tags: c++, qt

Slots in Qt can accept arguments. Where in the signal-sending process do these arguments get set? For instance, how would I go about writing my own custom signal/slot pair so that when the signal is emitted, a given value is sent to the slot as an argument?